# What style do I need to apply to a bootstrap modal-body to have it fill the available space of the modal-content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I have tried setting the height of `modal-body` to `100%` and `auto`. Setting to `100%` makes the modal-body the exact same height as `modal-content` which pushes the `modal-footer` outside of the modal.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3UrW/2/) for a demo of the problem.

Given a variable height for a modal (based on vh) with fixed heights for the header and footer, I would like the body to fill the rest of the space.

**Can this be done with pure CSS?**

Comment: "Can this be done with pure CSS?"  I don't believe so.  I had the same requirement and I had to use jQuery to detect the available height via $(window).height() and then calculate and set the modal-body height accordingly.

Comment: @PhilNicholas Agreed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on a pure CSS solution. See this updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3UrW/5/) for my working answer.

HTML:

```
<button>show</button>
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">header</div>
            <div class="modal-body">body</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".modal").modal("show");
});

$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    resizeModal($(this));
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeModal($(".modal"));
});

function resizeModal($modal) {
    var $modalDialog = $modal.find(".modal-dialog");
    var modalDialogTotalMargin = parseInt($modalDialog.css("margin-top")) + parseInt($modalDialog.css("margin-bottom"));
    var height = $(window).height() - modalDialogTotalMargin - $modalDialog.find(".modal-header").outerHeight(true) - $modalDialog.find(".modal-footer").outerHeight(true) - 1;
    $modalDialog.find(".modal-body").css({
        height: height
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.modal-dialog {
    /* basically full screen */
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 90vw;
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: black;
}
.modal-header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
}
.modal-body {
    background-color: blue;
}
.modal-footer {
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px;
}
```